# Recompile c++ API for minGw compiler in eclipse

Tags: c++, eclipse, mingw

The c++ api that i am using is compiled for visual studio 2010. Now i want to transfer my project for minGw compiler since i want to link the other project parts with the exisiting part. I have tried to link the project in eclipse but there several linker errors which i get.There are few shared libraries and few static libraries. There is a DLL which has the source code. (TB5CPP.dll)

Shared libraries: TB5CPP.dll; Tb5OT.dll;TB5STACK.dll;TB5UTIL.dll;ErrorReport.dll;libeay.dll;NodeSet2Import.dll

Static libraries:TB5CPP.lib; Utilities.lib

g++ -IC:/ProgramData/Softing/OPCUACppToolkit/V5.30/Windows/Source/Core/include/ -IC:/ProgramData/Softing/OPCUACppToolkit/V5.30/Windows/Source/api/include/ -O0 -g3 -Wall -c -fmessage-length=0 -o sampleClient.o "..\sampleClient.cpp" 
g++ "-LC:\ProgramData\Softing\OPCUACppToolkit\V5.30\Windows\Source\bin\Win32\VS2010\Debug\" -shared -o libsampleClient.exe sampleClient.o -lTB5CPP -lTB5OT -lTB5STACK -lTB5UTIL -llibeay32 -lErrorReport -lNodeSet2Import

sampleClient.o: In function `main':
D:\workspace\sampleClient\Debug_win32/../sampleClient.cpp:71: undefined reference to`_imp___ZN18SoftingOPCToolbox511loadToolboxEPNS_7CreatorE'
D:\workspace\sampleClient\Debug_win32/../sampleClient.cpp:74: undefined reference to `_imp___Z23getEnumStatusCodeString17tagEnumStatusCode'
D:\workspace\sampleClient\Debug_win32/../sampleClient.cpp:83: undefined reference to`_imp___Z23getEnumStatusCodeString17tagEnumStatusCode'
collect2: ld returned 1 exit status

Is it possible to use microsoft DLL in for minGw compiler?
Is there something like batch build in eclipse like it is there in visual studio to recompile the source code ?
How can i recompile from a dll file in eclipse for mingw compiler ?

Comment: Eclipse doesn't have to do with your problem primarily. It's the toolchain (compiler) actually used (the results aren't necessarily compatible). You can use MSVC compiler as toolchain for eclipse projects.

Comment: Yes but i need to use mingw compiler since the project that i am developing has to be compiled on mingw compiler. The problem was the toolkit which i was using had sent me the source code compiled for MSVC compiler.Now i have to recompile the source for mingw compiler.